# How to create a local repository using apt-mirror and mirrorkit?

Tags: repository, rsync, mirrors, apt-mirror

Having a local repository can be very useful. It is possible to use `rsync` to create a repository mirror, but this results in *all* the releases being downloaded, even older ones and would include files for architectures that might not be needed.

`apt-mirror` allows one to selectively choose parts of the repository. `mirrorkit` provides a front-end to apt-mirror.

**What is the best way to create a local repository mirror for selected parts of the Ubuntu archives?**

For example, one might wish to include:

- Main, Restricted, Universe, Multiverse, 
  All Ubuntu and Lubuntu but exclude other derivatives, such as Kubuntu and Xubuntu.
- Only AMD64 and i386 but exclude other architectures.
- Only Trusty Tahr, but not Precise Penguin or Utopic Unicorn.

One might wish to configure the process so that it downloaded from a local mirror, rather than the main archives.

How can I create local repository using `apt-mirror` and `mirrorkit` for a selected architecture, release, or Ubuntu variant?

Comment: Exclude Kubuntu? You mean exclude the Kubuntu ISOs or exclude any package that is being used by Kubuntu?

Comment: Exclude the Kubuntu and Xubuntu ISOs, for example. Perhaps there are an awful lot of them (Precise Kubuntu ARM, Precise Kubuntu i386, Quantal Kubuntu ARM, Quantal Kubuntu i386...) and the initial mirror download could be finished more rapidly without those ISOs. But if it is only a few more Gigabytes, perhaps it doesn't matter so much.

Comment: The ISOs are hosted separately from the packages. So you can use apt-mirror as you normally would to mirror the package repositories, and use some other tool for the ISOs. The question then becomes finding appropriate exclude filters for that tool (say rsync).

Comment: "you can use apt-mirror as you normally would" I am sorry, I don't know how to do that. This is exactly what I would like to be explained.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CD repository and software repository are two distinct components (they even have separate Launchpad pages: [cdmirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors) and [archivemirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors)). Therefore, mirroring them are two distinct tasks. Further, while the various flavours have different folders on the CD repository, they share a software repository. So you can selectively mirror the images per flavour, but not the software. For the software repository, you can selectively mirror based on:

- release (`trusty`, `precise`, etc.)
- architecture (`amd64`, `i386`, etc.)
- package type (binary [`deb`] vs source [`deb-src`])
- channels (`trusty`, `trusty-updates`, `trusty-backports`, etc.)
- sections (`main`, `multiverse`, etc.)

To mirror the software repository, use [`apt-mirror`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apt-mirror/).

`apt-mirror` is configured using [`/etc/apt/mirror.list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/apt-mirror.1.html). It has a format very similar to [`sources.list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sources.list.5.html). The configuration file installed by the package has a few commented out options which list their defaults. If you wish, you can uncomment and change them.

To mirror a repository, you need to add a line to `mirror.list` like you would for `sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe
```

The default is to mirror only the host's architecture, so if you're on a 64-bit Ubuntu, only `amd64` will be mirrored. You need to add another line of the form:

```
deb-i386 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe
```

And for source packages:

```
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe
```

If you're looking for a reasonably complete mirror, these lines would be the minimum (I would also recommend `-updates` channel):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb-i386 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe
deb-i386 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main multiverse restricted universe
```

Finally, you need to add a [`clean` line](https://askubuntu.com/a/538135/158442) so that packages no longer available in the repository are filtered for removal:

```
clean http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Say your variables are thus (the defaults):

```
set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
set skel_path    $base_path/skel
set var_path     $base_path/var
set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
```

Then:

- The repository will be mirrored to `$mirror_path/parent-hostname/directory` (so `/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`)
- The `clean.sh` (which will be a set of `rm` commands to delete obsolete packages and directories) will be `/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh`.
- The logs will go to `/var/spool/apt-mirror/var`.

The `apt-mirror` package installs a cron job (`/etc/cron.d/apt-mirror`), which you should edit to enable (by uncommenting the line containing `/usr/bin/apt-mirror`). You should also add a cron job for running `clean.sh` (I run it weekly).

Of course, you should replace `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com./ubuntu` with whichever mirror you prefer.

Comment: Is it really `deb-amd64` or `deb arch=amd64`? I can only find the latter one in manpage

Comment: @Anwar the former. The latter is for `sources.list`, which has a similar but not identical format. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/apt-mirror.1.html, where `deb-powerpc` is in the example.

Comment: Oh! I didn't have experience with apt-mirror. Thought it was for `sources.list`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recommend apt-cacher for those with limited space or those having exhorbitant internet prices in their countries.

apt-mirror, allegedly, requires at least 15GB for each flavour (32/64 bit) of the distro you want. apt-cacher only uses the packages you have installed.

Read [Create a Local Ubuntu Repository using Apt-Mirror and Apt-Cacher](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-apt-cacher) for more details/instructions please.