# local apt-mirror not finding packages

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

I am attempting to setup a mirror of the Ubuntu packages on a local server for use on a local network that will not be connected to the internet for extended periods. I have followed the instructions from a few sites, mainly this [one](https://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror_p3), that shows how to use apt-mirror to do this. I believe I have the server setup correctly. It downloaded Gb's worth of data and said it succeeded. I then setup an nginx server and I can go to the site using my ip address and see the folder and the dists and pool folders. dists contains the bionic folders in it. I then modified my /etc/apt/sources.list file on my client computer and changed it to point to the ip address of my server instead of the ubuntu archive sites. Here is what it looks like now:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

I also modified the mirror.list file before download to pull bionic, and in my dists folder bionic is there and full of packages. I then ran sudo apt-get update and I got this output:

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]                   
Get:2 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]          
Get:3 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]        
Get:4 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]         
Ign:5 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages                   
Get:6 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,019 kB]       
Get:7 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [516 kB]         
Get:8 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]  
Get:9 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [118 kB]     
Get:10 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [245 kB]    
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Ign:33 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Get:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]  
Ign:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages            
Ign:43 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages              
Ign:44 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages            
Ign:5 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages                   
Ign:45 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages          
Ign:46 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages    
Ign:47 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages      
Ign:48 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages    
Get:49 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]            
Get:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,852 B]
Get:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,852 B]
Get:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,852 B]
Get:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,852 B]
Get:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,852 B]
Ign:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages   
Ign:56 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages    
Ign:57 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe Translation-en   
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Get:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Ign:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:66 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:67 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:68 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages       
Ign:69 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages   
Ign:70 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages      
Ign:43 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages        
Ign:44 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages      
Ign:5 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages             
Ign:45 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages    
Ign:46 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:47 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:48 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:71 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]  
Ign:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages   
Ign:56 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages    
Ign:57 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:66 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:67 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:68 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages         
Ign:69 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages     
Ign:70 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages   
Ign:11 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages            
Ign:43 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages              
Ign:44 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages         
Err:5 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages                
404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.10.118 80]
Ign:45 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages       
Ign:46 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:47 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:48 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:56 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:57 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:58 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:66 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.10.118 80]
Ign:67 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:68 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages      
Ign:69 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages  
Ign:70 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:45 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages       
404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.10.118 80]
Ign:46 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages 
Ign:47 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages   
Ign:48 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages 
Ign:50 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:56 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages 
Err:68 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages      
404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.10.118 80]
Ign:69 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages  
Ign:70 http://192.168.10.118/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

So it is finding the packages in the mirror. I am a bit concerned about the Ign:XX. I am unsure if this means it is ignoring it? When I go to actually try and install something basic like git it fails.

```
sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate


sudo apt-get install git-gui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git-gui
```

I have tried installing a number of basic packages, but so far I always get the same message saying it could not be found. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be going wrong here, or what I can try to figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue one:

If you look toward the bottom of your modified mirror.list, this line here is a problem:

```
   E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
```

I just had this same problem and it's an easy fix. It's happening because the company owning the APT repository has changed it's name from Google Inc to Google LLC. 
Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
```

You will, then, be prompted to accept the new origin of the repository:

```
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

Type "y" and you're good to go. That's it.

Issue two:

See if this exists:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

If it does, it needs to be deleted like this:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

Next

The architecture may need to be added to the sources.list, something like this example:

```
deb [arch=amd64] file:/wherever ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse ...etc.
```

The updates should now work.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned. It I did accept the changes and that part seemed to work, but I still get the same error when I try and install things like git.

Comment: I'm glad to have solved one of the problems. I think this here will get you up and running the rest of the way: https://askubuntu.com/questions/551064/how-to-create-a-local-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-mirrorkit

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I really appreciate it. However, I did setup my mirror list and I am pretty sure it downloaded the correct files. Both my mirror.list on my server, and my sources list on client are setup for bionic, but when I try and use the mirror to install something on the client it says it cannot find the package. So there is a disconnect somewhere. I am just not sure where. I also checked in the mirror data as well. I can find git in the security section and its deb in pools. So the data is there, my client is just not finding it for some reason.

Comment: See if you have this: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream . If you do, it needs to be deleted like this: sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream . You may have to add the architecture to the sources.list (ex. deb [arch=amd64] file:/wherever ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
...etc.).

Comment: Awesome! That got it. Deleting the 50appstream did not change anything, but specifying the arch fixed the problem. I am now able to install stuff using my cloned repo. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Happy I was able to help.